# Sort CSV on date column in Python while ignoring null cell values

Tags: python, csv

I have the following code:

```
 with closing(requests.get(CSV_URL, stream=False, verify=False)) as result:
    reader = csv.reader(result.iter_lines(), delimiter=',', quotechar='"')

    # skip the header
    reader.next()

    # sort on date column
    col = 2
    filteredRows = filter(lambda x: len(x) > col, reader)
    sortedRows = sorted(filteredRows, key=lambda row: time.strptime(row[2].strip(), "%m/%d/%Y"), reverse=True)
```

If I don't sort I can iterate through the rows fine. The error I get is:

```
ValueError: time data '' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y'
```

Clearly the rows with empty columns are not being filtered. Any pointers on how I can get this to work would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the simpliest solution would be to modify filter call and ignore rows with empty data column:

```
filteredRows = filter(lambda x: len(x) > col and x[col].strip(), reader)
```

I'd suggest checking, why you're getting empty data. Unless it's acceptable (data has empty rows for example).

PS. You should probably use col instead of 2 in last line, right?